# Are these canned dolmas safe to eat, why are they pink?

Tags: color

My canned dolmas (grape-leaf wrapped rice) are marked as expiring in 2023, but when I opened them they both had pink spots and the oil that pours off had some pink watery color to it.

The discoloration only occurred where the rice was exposed to the oil, if you peeled back the grape leaves the rice was white.

Smelled normal and tasted normal (the non-pink ones that I ate before I spotted the discoloration).

[image: canned dolmas pic]

Comment: The pink spot in each can looks like it's part of the filling. What kind of filling do they have?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be tannins from the grape leaves. The water in my jars of grape leaves is usually colored slightly red. It makes sense that the rice would be stained pink where there is contact with the leaf.